# Binding HTML rather than plain text

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

How can one include HTML rather than plain text in Polymer. Let's say one retrieves through ajax an array of strings which include `<i>` and `<strong>` elements and you wish to render those with a `dom-repeat` `<template>` (or an `<iron-list>` as is the case in my specific scenario). How would you do this so the HTML renders as actual HTML?

Comment: probably related: https://github.com/Polymer/TemplateBinding/issues/57

Comment: @Claies Yeah, came across that link in my own research as well, but considering the year (Polymer is nearly 3 years old and those posts are 2 years old) I wasn't sure whether I should take that as a 'no, not possible'.

Comment: it's still open, and there are a few posts suggesting alternatives, including a couple posts from this year showing some workarounds.

Comment: @Claies It's all Polymer 0.5 stuff, check the tags ;-) But yeah, I might actually have an idea how the same thing could be hacked together in Polymer 1, but I would greatly prefer not needing to resort to those kind of hacks O:) . Though if there are no other ways I guess I don't have a choice.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly hack-ish way to bind a node's `innerHTML` property:

```
<div inner-h-t-m-l="{{myProp}}"></div>
```

Polymer infers capitalization from hyphens, translating the following character to uppercase.

Comment: Note this is considered "unsafe", so make sure your data is properly sanitized if you're going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found was to create an element `<bind-html>` with the following definition:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="bind-html">

  <template></template>

</dom-module>

<script>

  Polymer({

    is: 'bind-html',
    properties: {
      html: {
        type: String,
        observer: ["htmlChanged"]
      }
    },
    htmlChanged: function(value){
      Polymer.dom(this.root).innerHTML = value;
    }

  });

</script>
```

Just as I posted this Zikes posted another solution, so I have to yet look into which one works best, but at least wanted to quickly drop this here in case it turns out to be useful for someone.

---

Thanks to @Claies for pointing out that I hadn't been reading carefully enough and re-directing me to some Polymer 0.5 discussions which helped out.